# error massage of "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" cant i change'r' to 'w' but still didnt work

Tags: python, text-files

```
with open('/Users/harryhou/Desktop/project 830/ass 2/supermarket_sales.csv', 'r') as SalesList:
    for row in SalesList:
        print(SalesList.readline())
        for row in SalesList:
            print(row)
##Write a function to receive the Supermarket Sales list (that you created in the previous question) and return the total sales (the sum of column Total) of the branches as a dictionary

##The returned information should look like (the numbers given below may not be correct):
##{"A": 123456.123, "B": 234567.567, "C": 345678.9987}

def totalSales(SalesList):
    dict2 ={'A':0, 'B':0,'C':0}
    for sale in SalesList:
        dict2[sale[1]] += sale[9]
    return dict2
print(totalSales(SalesList))
print(totalSales(SalesList))
```

Comment: You should read about `with open(...) as f:`. The file will be open only inside the `with` block.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not very clear, I think I see your problem.

You open and use a file handle at the top of your code via these lines:

```
with open('/Users/harryhou/Desktop/project 830/ass 2/supermarket_sales.csv', 'r') as SalesList:
    for row in SalesList:
       ...
```

Once the `with` block has completed, the file is closed.  That's the whole reason for using `with`.  It insures that the file gets closed after the block within the `with` is done executing.  You should never use the file handle associated with a `with` statement (`SalesList` in this case) outside of the block of code associated with that `with`.

I'm guessing that the error occurs on the first of these two lines that execute later in your code:

```
for sale in SalesList:
    dict2[sale[1]] += sale[9]
```

You're getting that error for exactly the reason that the error messages says...you're trying to operate on a closed file handle.  `SalesList` was used to represent the file that was opened by the `with` statement.  But that file has since been closed.  You should not be using `SalesList` for anything outside of the `with` code block.

Comment: thank you I will try it. but how do i actually "edit" or "write" on the csv instead of just reading it.

Comment: how to change it to make it work ?any suggestions would be highly appreciated it